# How can I open reactjs project in Visual Studio 2017 Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I created project by the command of 'create-react-app' and 'yo office'(https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-get-started-react)

I want to develop it by Visual Studio 2017 Professional,How can I do it?

Thank you.

Comment: If you want Visual Studio 2017 you can purchase it from Microsoft on their website.  The Community Edition is free and may work for you instead of paying for Visual Studio.  https://www.visualstudio.com

Comment: I'd recommend using Visual Studio Code for Reach based development..